# redhat oauth.so missing

Tags: php, linux, rhel

I tried to put the oauth on my redhat server, but since I got this message :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/oauth.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/oauth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Do someone know how to put that file on redhat ?
I'm not a Linux expert.

Thank you

Comment: Well, where did you put it, if not in the `/usr/lib/php/modules/` directory?

Comment: Btw, it seems there is a pre-packed version for Redhat (no installation woes). http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/16821219/dir/redhat_el_5/com/php-pecl-oauth-1.2.2-1.el5.remi.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: @mario I got no idea where it is...

Comment: how can I put that library ? cause seems to not existe

Comment: Please don't speak in riddles. Explain in detail what you've tried. -- Have you installed the RPM? If not, what have you installed? ***How*** have you installed the oauth.so module if anything?

Comment: ok this is cause of Friday I tried to install Oauth, I installed the package with "yum install pcre prce-devel" then "pecl install oauth" I put a file to "/etc/php.d/" called "oauth.ini" containing "extension=oauth.so"
but seems to not work, I just commented that file for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the generated `oauth.so` file.

To do so run (as superuser):

```
updatedb
locate oauth.so
```

Then copy that complete path into the `/etc/php.d/oauth.ini`.

Usually it's `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo.so`

Comment: This seems good but... how do we use updatedb ?

Comment: I did under SU :
updatedb
then a blank space comes, I type :
locate oauth.so
but nothing happens, if I pres enter there is just a new line I need to do Ctrl+c to exit...

Comment: `updatedb` takes a while. Cancelling does not usally lead to results. Use `find / -name oauth.so` instead. Also takes time. (But if for some reason you won't just look yourself...)